# How to configure a GKE node so that a previously assigned IP address is reassigned

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster of two nodes on Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine. Each node is assigned a static IP address. In the screenshot, these are the IP addresses of minion-1 and minion-2. There is the following problem. Sometimes Google Cloud re-creates these nodes, and the name of the node changes. After that, the IP addresses minion-1 and minion-2 are not assigned to any node. Newly created nodes are assigned dynamic IP addresses. I have to manually assign old static IP addresses to these nodes. I didn't find an answer in the Google Cloud documentation. How to configure a node so that after creating a node, the previously assigned IP address is automatically assigned to the node?

[image: Screen Cluster]

[image: Screen IP address]

Comment: Could you please tell me why do you need static IPs and specific names of your nodes?

Comment: This node runs a web service that sends data to our company. And at the entrance to the company's network, there is a restriction of incoming requests by IP address.

Comment: How do you expose your web service?

Comment: The service has already been working great, for several years. There are no questions about the service. There is a problem that I described above.

Comment: If your current solution requires manual adjustment after some usual GKE operation it's not the only way to do it. Your problem could be solved in different ways, but to do it you should provide more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not fully understand what other details need to be clarified. I need a static IP address on the node. A static IP address is assigned to the node, everything works fine. But when Google kills a node and creates this node again, the previously assigned IP address remains free, not assigned to the node. I suppose that I need to specify the IP address in the node configuration, but I did not find this in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, because there's no such option like static IP for your node. GKE relies on the DNS names, not on the static IPs. Static IP could be on the LoadBanancer/Ingress which you can use to expose your service.

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza We're talking about outbound requests that a web service sends out from a node. I thought outbound requests were bypassing Ingress. I thought that Ingress is needed only for incoming requests. Ingress is configured on my instance to receive incoming requests. Please tell me that a static IP address is assigned to a node, do I need to make changes to the Ingress configuration?

Comment: I see, if your service initialize connect from GCP to on-promises resources you can change your configuration to use Cloud NAT where you can set static IP. In this case you'll get same source external IP.